# Java Deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, fasterxml

I have xml response like that

```
        <service>Service name</service>
        ...
        some fields
        ...
        <service>
            <min_amount>6</min_amount>
            <max_amount>1522</max_amount>
            <max_limit>3000</max_limit>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </service>
```

and i need to deserialize it into POJO

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "service")
private String service;

... some more fields ...

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "service")
private Service serviceObject;
```

but i'm getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple fields representing property "service", how can i solve that?

Comment: Your xml does not seem to be correctly indented. Is second service tag wrapped in something ?

Comment: The first "service" parameter is a basic string but second one is a XML class, both them are in same scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your XML response is not valid, so it may be impossible to map it correctly for (de)serialization.

You have two tags with the same name `service` , but with different structure.

I assume you are not the owner of service, producing this XML, but one of this tag should be rename, or two separate namespaces should be used for them.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML response is not right, because you are using the same tag names for two different things. One should be serviceName for example

```
        <serviceName>Service name</serviceName>
        ...
        some fields
        ...
        <service>
            <min_amount>6</min_amount>
            <max_amount>1522</max_amount>
            <max_limit>3000</max_limit>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </service>
```